# Selecting country and city

Tags: php, html, select

Are there php file with array with countries and cities, something like that:

```
$country[] = "Albania";
$country[] = "Algeria";
```

And the same with cities? Or are there any other, maybe better, solutions for showing countries for users and give them to select? Thanks.

Comment: For reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1 (since it's table should be easy to extract and turn into a php array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html):

```
$countries = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON'), true);
```

For cities you need to use the bounding box coordinates (available from the previous request result) and the [Cities method](http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html#citiesJSON), localization is also supported for most languages using the `lang` query string.

**EDIT**: You probably want to cache (or [download](http://www.geonames.org/export/)) these results to avoid overloading GeoNames server.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't something like this built into PHP. You'll have to find a country list and either parse it with PHP or store it in a MySQL table.

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach if you don't want to use a database is to use a webservice to provide you with a list
like: [This one](http://www.geonames.org/)

Answer (score 1):

### Countries

I've just exported this list from my database.

```
$countries = array(
  1 => "Afghanistan",
  2 => "Albania",
  3 => "Algeria",
  4 => "American Samoa",
  5 => "Andorra",
  6 => "Angola",
  7 => "Anguilla",
  8 => "Antarctica",
  9 => "Antigua & Barbuda",
  10 => "Argentina",
  11 => "Armenia",
  12 => "Aruba",
  13 => "Australia",
  14 => "Austria",
  15 => "Azerbaijan",
  16 => "Bahamas",
  17 => "Bahrain",
  18 => "Bangladesh",
  19 => "Barbados",
  20 => "Belarus",
  21 => "Belgium",
  22 => "Belize",
  23 => "Benin",
  24 => "Bermuda",
  25 => "Bhutan",
  26 => "Bolivia",
  27 => "Bosnia & Herzegovina",
  28 => "Botswana",
  29 => "Bouvet Island",
  30 => "Brazil",
  31 => "British Indian Ocean Territory",
  32 => "Brunei",
  33 => "Bulgaria",
  34 => "Burkina Faso",
  35 => "Burundi",
  36 => "Cambodia",
  37 => "Cameroon",
  38 => "Canada",
  39 => "Cape Verde",
  40 => "Cayman Islands",
  41 => "Central African Republic",
  42 => "Chad",
  43 => "Chile",
  44 => "China",
  45 => "Chinese Taipei/Taiwan",
  46 => "Colombia",
  47 => "Comoros",
  48 => "Congo",
  49 => "Congo,DR",
  50 => "Cook Islands",
  51 => "Costa Rica",
  52 => "Cote d' Ivoire",
  53 => "Croatia",
  54 => "Cuba",
  55 => "Cyprus",
  56 => "Czech Republic",
  57 => "Denmark",
  58 => "Djibouti",
  59 => "Dominica",
  60 => "Dominican Republic",
  61 => "Ecuador",
  62 => "Egypt",
  63 => "El Salvador",
  64 => "Equatorial Guinea",
  65 => "Eritrea",
  66 => "Estonia",
  67 => "Ethiopia",
  68 => "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)",
  69 => "Faroe Islands",
  70 => "Fiji",
  71 => "Finland",
  72 => "France",
  73 => "French Guiana",
  74 => "French Polynesia",
  75 => "Gabon",
  76 => "Gambia",
  77 => "Georgia",
  78 => "Germany",
  79 => "Ghana",
  80 => "Gibraltar",
  81 => "Great Britain",
  82 => "Greece",
  83 => "Greenland",
  84 => "Grenada",
  85 => "Guadeloupe",
  86 => "Guam",
  87 => "Guatemala",
  88 => "Guinea",
  89 => "Guinea-Bissau",
  90 => "Guyana",
  91 => "Haiti",
  92 => "Heard Island and McDonald Islands",
  93 => "Honduras",
  94 => "Hong Kong",
  95 => "Hungary",
  96 => "Iceland",
  97 => "India",
  98 => "Indonesia",
  99 => "Iran",
  100 => "Iraq",
  101 => "Ireland",
  102 => "Israel",
  103 => "Italy",
  104 => "Jamaica",
  105 => "Japan",
  106 => "Jordan",
  107 => "Kazakhstan",
  108 => "Kenya",
  109 => "Kiribati",
  110 => "Korea",
  111 => "Kuwait",
  112 => "Kyrgyzstan",
  113 => "Lao",
  114 => "Latvia",
  115 => "Lebanon",
  116 => "Lesotho",
  117 => "Liberia",
  118 => "Libya",
  119 => "Liechtenstein",
  120 => "Lithuania",
  121 => "Luxembourg",
  122 => "Macau",
  123 => "Macedonia, FYR",
  124 => "Madagascar",
  125 => "Malawi",
  126 => "Malaysia",
  127 => "Maldives",
  128 => "Mali",
  129 => "Malta",
  130 => "Marshall Islands",
  131 => "Martinique",
  132 => "Mauritania",
  133 => "Mauritius",
  134 => "Mayotte",
  135 => "Mexico",
  136 => "Micronesia",
  137 => "Moldova",
  138 => "Monaco",
  139 => "Mongolia",
  140 => "Montenegro",
  141 => "Montserrat",
  142 => "Morocco",
  143 => "Mozambique",
  144 => "Myanmar",
  145 => "Namibia",
  146 => "Nauru",
  147 => "Nepal",
  148 => "Netherlands",
  149 => "Netherlands Antilles",
  150 => "New Caledonia",
  151 => "New Zealand",
  152 => "Nicaragua",
  153 => "Niger",
  154 => "Nigeria",
  155 => "Niue",
  156 => "Norfolk Island",
  157 => "North Korea",
  158 => "Northern Mariana Islands",
  159 => "Norway",
  160 => "Oman",
  161 => "Pakistan",
  162 => "Palau",
  163 => "Palestine",
  164 => "Panama",
  165 => "Papua New Guinea",
  166 => "Paraguay",
  167 => "Peru",
  168 => "Philippines",
  169 => "Poland",
  170 => "Portugal",
  171 => "Puerto Rico",
  172 => "Qatar",
  173 => "Reunion",
  174 => "Romania",
  175 => "Russia",
  176 => "Rwanda",
  177 => "Samoa",
  178 => "San Marino",
  179 => "Sao Tome & Principe",
  180 => "Saudi Arabia",
  181 => "Senegal",
  182 => "Serbia",
  183 => "Seychelles",
  184 => "Sierra Leone",
  185 => "Singapore",
  186 => "Slovakia",
  187 => "Slovenia",
  188 => "Solomon Islands",
  189 => "Somalia",
  190 => "South Africa",
  191 => "Spain",
  192 => "Sri Lanka",
  193 => "St.Kitts & Nevis",
  194 => "St.Lucia",
  195 => "St.Vincent & the Grenadines",
  196 => "Sudan",
  197 => "Suriname",
  198 => "Swaziland",
  199 => "Sweden",
  200 => "Switzerland",
  201 => "Syria",
  202 => "Tajikistan",
  203 => "Tanzania",
  204 => "Thailand",
  205 => "Timor-Leste",
  206 => "Togo",
  207 => "Tokelau",
  208 => "Tonga",
  209 => "Trinidad & Tobago",
  210 => "Tunisia",
  211 => "Turkey",
  212 => "Turkmenistan",
  213 => "Turks and Caicos Islands",
  214 => "Tuvalu",
  215 => "Uganda",
  216 => "Ukraine",
  217 => "United Arab Emirates",
  218 => "United States",
  219 => "United States Minor Outlying Islands",
  220 => "Uruguay",
  221 => "Uzbekistan",
  222 => "Vanuatu",
  223 => "Vatican City State",
  224 => "Venezuela",
  225 => "Vietnam",
  226 => "Virgin Islands (UK)",
  227 => "Virgin Islands (USA)",
  228 => "Wallis and Futuna",
  229 => "Yemen",
  230 => "Zambia",
  231 => "Zimbabwe"
}
```

About cities, I can't help.